# How to put word between the symbols?

Tags: regex, notepad++

i want put word between the symbols in notepad++ (regex)
for example i have this list of symbols:

```
!@#!@#
#@!#@!
#$%#$%
%$#%$#
```

and i want put (word) between the previous symbols for example:

```
!@#word!@#
#@!word#@!
#$%word#$%
%$#word%$#
```

what regex can help me?

Comment: That is really easy with lookarounds. `(?<=!@#)(?=!@#)|(?<=#@!)(?=#@!)|(?<=#\$%)(?=#\$%)|(?<=%\$#)(?=%\$#)` and replace with `word`.

Comment: i tried but only back me two lines edited
!@#word!@#
#@!word#@!
@#$^%&
!@#^%$
and this is really long regex

Comment: SO adds garbage chars into code inside comments. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/kzyeDd/1).

Comment: can you help me how to make regex like this for notepad++??
i'm not programer 

Comment: You do not need to be a programmer to copy and paste text from regex101  into a Notepad++ S&R window.

Comment: ok but i want learn (how to make a notepad++ regex by regex101.com without learn programming?)
have any tutrial video??

Comment: Go to http://regexone.com, but then you will need to study much more. In Notepad++, Boost is used (search Boost regex documentation in Google).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=!@#)(?=!@#)|(?<=#@!)(?=#@!)|(?<=#\$%)(?=#\$%)|(?<=%\$#)(?=%\$#)
```

and replace with `word`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzyeDd/1).